# Chart library for Qt

Tags: c++, qt, graph, charts

Is there any open-source or free chart library for Qt? I only need XY charts, not bar charts or anything else.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's two I know of:

- [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/)
- [QtiPlot](http://soft.proindependent.com/qtiplot.html): the app is paid, but the code is not I think (you can download the source)

Comment: Just FYI: I just found out QtiPlot uses Qwt internally, so it might be better to just use Qwt for all your plotting needs directly :)

Comment: I like the Qt Commercial Charts but they are "Commercial" http://qt.digia.com/Product/Qt-Add-Ons/Charts/

Answer (score 24):

QCustomPlot is a rather compact Qt widget for plotting, with the possibility of extension to your needs, under the GPL license. It has no further dependencies and is fully documented, including internal functions.

Check [the QCustomPlot website](http://www.qcustomplot.com/).

Comment: Found that stuff, and was very impressed! Its great!

Comment: Unfortunately it has that GPL license...

Comment: @JosephMalicke: build it as separate process with open code and communicate over IPC

Answer (score 4):

[KD Chart](http://nixbit.com/cat/science-and-engineering/visualization/kd-chart-2.0/)

Comment: Where the offical website is http://www.kdab.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=55&Itemid=65 
KD Chart is dual-licensed, commercial and GPL. There is no public download page, one might have to contact KDAB to obtain it. Projects like KOffice also have it in their repositories.

Comment: perhaps you can get some versions from following repository (check out 28094257): https://projects.kde.org/projects/kde/kdeedu/ktouch/repository/show/src?rev=master