# Millimeter paper in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, grid, draw, qwidget

I have to paint a millimeter grid on my widget. Does any class exist that can help me to do that?
I need it to paint some math charts.

Comment: When you draw items on a computer screen, you specify the drawing in pixels rather than millimetres. Are you aiming for something you can print to a printer in millimetres, or are you trying to achieve an accurate millimetre dimension on screen?

Comment: You need to know the screen resolution and physical width and height of the screen in order to know how to map the pixels.

Comment: Im trying to achieve an accurate millimetre dimension on screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before reinventing the wheel please take in account some charting libraries as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537251/chart-library-for-qt). Both `QCustomPlot` and `Qwt` are easy to include and not that difficult to customize. Both provide several examples; possibly one of them could be the solution addressing your issue.

---

If the available libraries don't fulfill your needs you can create your own solution by *subclassing* `QWidget` and *reimplementing* the `painEvent()`. [`QPainter`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qpainter.html) and [`QPainterPath`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qpainterpath.html) are key classes for the task.
`Qt` provides a lot of [interesting tutorials](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/examples-painting.html), especially "Basic Drawing Example" and "Painter Paths Example". Probably you would also enjoy [this simple example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-analogclock-example.html) or [this one](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QPainter.php). Starting from these references you should be able to draw your grid easily.

Finally, the [Graphics View Framework](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/graphicsview.html) contains the [`QGraphicsScene`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html) which (citing docs)

> provides a surface for managing a large number of 2D graphical items.

Such a class has been used for [charting purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161064/drawing-plot-lines-on-qgraphicsscene) and [grids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279567/qt-gui-development-displaying-a-2d-grid-using-qgraphicsview), exploiting painting APIs introduced above. While using this class it is crucial, to guarantee an overall good performance, to draw the grid in the `drawBackground()` function as done for instance [here](http://tufangorel.blogspot.it/2011/08/draw-grid-on-qgraphicsscene.html) (or use a background bitmap).

---

All the API discussed work in *pixels*. If you are really concerned with *exact* millimeters representation on screen, you can exploit the `QScreen` object, directly accessible from your `qApp` pointer. It provides several functions, in particular `physicalDotsPerInch()` (`logicalDotsPerInch()` for Android since the other returns an infinite value on KitKat). A pixel approximation for a millimeter can be calculated as follows:

```
int dotPerMillimeter = qRound(qApp->primaryScreen()->physicalDotsPerInch() / 25.4)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I can't use Qwt etc to achieve this in my project. But your formula can be helpful. Thanks

Comment: I see. Well, consider also [this nice answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828636/efficiently-painting-physically-accurate-ruler-in-qt). The purpose was to draw a ruler but you can build on that (and my formula) to achieve your goal.