# Efficiently painting physically accurate ruler in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a ruler class (called `Graduation`) that uses orientation to calculate where lines should be drawn.  So like this:

[image]

When the orientation is set to `Qt::Horizontal` I do `line_xpos = precendent_line_xpos + number`.  Then if the orientation is `Qt::Vertical` I add to the y position.

I have some code below which is an example of how I do this with `if...else` and `?:` statements:

```
/* std::vector<QLineF> m_lines; */

void Graduation::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{   
    qreal newLength = (m_orientation == Qt::Horizontal)
        ? event->size().width()
        : event->size().height();
    qreal oldLength = (m_orientation == Qt::Horizontal)
        ? event->oldSize().width()
        : event->oldSize().height();

    if(newLength != oldLength) {
        if(newLength < oldLength) { /* Delete lines */
            int count = m_lines.size();
            if(count == 0)
                return;

            if(m_orientation == Qt::Horizontal) {
                while(m_lines[count-1].x1() > newLength) {
                    --count;
                }
            } else {
                while(m_lines[count-1].y1() > newLength) {
                    --count;
                }
            }

            m_lines.erase(
                m_lines.begin()+count,
                m_lines.begin()+m_lines.size()
            );
        } else
          /* ... Append lines ... */
    }
}
```

Here is the paintEvent to show how the lines are drawn:

```
void Graduation::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event)

    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 0.5));

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < m_lines.size(); ++i)
        painter.drawLine(m_lines[i]);
}
```

I want to know if I can keep from having those conditions checked possibly thousands of times.  I'm interested in what code pattern you can use to avoid that *(although it could be better to calculate lines position only one time and draw only what is visible)*.

Comment: Function pointer, functor, lambda

Comment: @deviantfan. How can I use function pointer on m_lines[count-1].x1() when pointed object changes each iteration.

Comment: @Eliot545 Thanks for editing your question, I've embedded the image for you (you'll be able to do it yourself after some more reputation points...) Please note the correct spelling of the English word [`Length`](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/length)  Also, if your pattern is regular then having storage of each pair of endpoints for your line locations is not necessary; e.g. a million pixel wide widget should not need to put every line to be drawn into a vector.  *(Unless they can be moved somehow by the user, or something, and thus need to have storage of where they are moved to?)*

Comment: @HostileFork I was surprised to read my question in a good English, what a shock! Thanks

Comment: @Eliot545 You may want to look at [QicsRuler](http://www.ics.com/files/docs/qicstable/2.1/classQicsRuler.html) and the [QicsRuler.cpp](https://gitorious.org/qicstable/qicstable/source/196c68ed80f44632a1613bba41f773f754101dcf:src/QicsRuler.cpp) file for ideas on an implementation that does not store any points.  Regarding your abstract question, I'm not sure what the "tens of thousands of if/elses" are...there are two `?:` and one `if/else` conditional on m_orientation.  Are the rest of them in code we don't see here, or do you consider 3 to be a lot?

Comment: @Eliot545 After adding the paint routine, I still don't think I understand where you think the thousands of checks are that are happening (in your abstract question about design techniques).  Is your concern that the `if...else` and `?:` runs on every resize event?  These are not very frequent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, after you posted that image, it does look like you can go for a much simpler and effective solution.

Your lines form a repeatable pattern and as such, it would be a waste to draw the whole thing, manage lines manually and whatnot. You can create a small pixmap and draw only one segment of the repeating pattern like this:

[image: pattern]

Then depending on the orientation you can leave it as it is or rotate/flip it. Then you can use `QPainter` to fill your `Graduation` widget with it a `Qt::TexturePattern` using `QBrush::setTexture(pixmap)` and it will quickly and efficiently fill the entire widget length/height with the pattern, regardless of how much it is.

If you want to change the style or spacing of the ruler, all you have to do is redraw the cached pattern and use the same process to update the rulers.

And last but not least, you can use the layouting Qt provides to snap your rulers to the right place so they are managed 100% automatically, making your currently used logic redundant.

OK, here is a little more help, plus this will show you you don't have to have each and every line to draw lines, the code is simple enough and will generate the pattern segment for a given DPI:

```
QPixmap drawCMPattern(qreal dpi) {
    qreal dpcm = dpi / 2.54;
    QPixmap rulerCache(dpcm, dpcm / 2);
    rulerCache.fill();
    qreal dpmm = dpcm / 10;
    QPainter p(&rulerCache);
    p.setRenderHint(QPainter::HighQualityAntialiasing);
    qreal lineWidth = dpmm / 5;
    p.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, lineWidth));
    qreal xpos = lineWidth / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        if (i == 0) p.drawLine(QLineF(xpos, 0, xpos, rulerCache.height()));
        else if (i == 5) p.drawLine(QLineF(xpos, 0, xpos, rulerCache.height() / 2));
        else p.drawLine(QLineF(xpos, 0, xpos, rulerCache.height() / 4));
        xpos += dpmm;
    }
    return rulerCache;
}
```

You may notice the lines are somewhat blurry on a typical low DPI desktop monitor, but that's the price you pay for being "physically accurate" - you are either metric perfect or pixel perfect, you can't have both unless your DPI match metric units perfectly, most lines are bound to happen between pixels. On a high DPI mobile device it will not look as bad.

Alternatively, you can get crisp lines if you omit the `HighQualityAntialiasing`, but then the lines will not be at equal distance. Still, this may prove good for you, since it is apparently good enough for commercial software like Photoshop:

[image: PS ruler]

PS is however tricky and has less lines in 1 cm, so the difference is not as striking as it is when having a line for each mm. Here is how that code result looks on my 108.79 DPI desktop:

[image: this code]

Comment: Thank you for this technique I did not know.
However in my mind I want the ruler to be calibrated in cm and inch and the lines can be glued to the top edge, center, or bottom edge of the widget and display the numbers in the longest lines.
Maybe the solution you propose is, then, not the most suitable.

Comment: It will still be more efficient, just add another painter pass in which you draw the numbers. There is nothing preventing you from calculating the right dimensions for the cache pixmap so that your rulers are physically accurate.

Comment: Ok! I going to try this solution. Thanks ddriver.

Comment: To have each and every line a separate entity is overkill to say the least. I can't tell how much overhead from just the code you posted, but it is entirely unnecessary. Even if you want some kind of "interaction" with the lines, like for example snapping or getting cursor feedback, it can exist purely theoretically and in numbers, without the need for lines to be separate entities. It will save you CPU time and memory, on top of the logic to manage all those lines.