# Dimensioning in Qt

Tags: qt

I have graphicsView in which different items are drawn in the scene.I want to have an option for dimensioning i.e to dimension.

There are different items like Line, Circle, Ellipse, Arc, Point, Text,
I want whenver the the two points are clicked on any item,or the anywhere on the scene it should tell me its dimension.

The items are drawn with the mouseclicks. Can I get help to proceed?

The items are inherited from QGraphicsItem, LineItem.

Like:https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yMSc.jpg

Comment: Welcome to SO. As we're a community of developers in a wide range of fields, your question as it stands is very broad and making the assumption that we know about CAD and "Linear dimensioning". I suggest you edit it to explain more clearly what it is that you're wanting to know, detailing what you're trying to achieve, without making assumptions about your specialist field of expertise, outside of programming.

Comment: This may help you somewhat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828636/efficiently-painting-physically-accurate-ruler-in-qt/26828913#26828913

Comment: Can I get some simple example, so as to do it?

Comment: That things are not needed, just want to click two points, a line gets drawn b/w two points and the dimension is shown:?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this to get the length in inches:

```
qreal distance(QPointF & p1, QPointF & p2) {
    return QLineF(p1, p2).length() / QApplication::screens().at(0)->physicalDotsPerInch();
}
```

Multiply by 2.54 if you want centimeters. Then create a `QGraphicsItem` which draws the line between the two points and text with the distance.

You can use `void QWidget::mousePress/Release/Event(QMouseEvent * event)` and get the click position from the `event->pos()`, and you should map to the scene coords when you are actually drawing the dimension.

If you don't want the actual line length but the horizontal or vertical length as in that image you posted as example, you can calculate that from the absolute difference between the two points x or y components.